# Cant pad with zeros so i can multiply by element two matrices (matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, matrix, padding

I got two matrices, `A` (inverse filter) and `B` (image in frequency domain, for simplicity values are zeros and ones)

```
A=ones(20,20);
B=zeros(33,33);
```

And i want to multiply them by element like this:

```
C=A.*B;
```

For purpose of signal processing (find in frequency domain the product and then transform back (image restoration).
To do this I should pad the smallest array so that it is `A[33,33]`, 
But when I pad like this

```
A=padarray(A,[7,7]);
```

Which makes `size(A)=(44,44);`
And then take something like this

```
A=A(1:33,1:33);
```

My image is not centered and I cant have the expecting result.
How can I pad image `A` so that it is centered and then multiply with `B`?

Comment: How exactly do you expect to center an even-sized matrix within an odd-sized matrix?

Comment: Have you considered replacing the central-frequency representation (i.e., DC component centered) with a zero-frequency representation (i.e., DC component at the top left corner)? Look at [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) and [`ifftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifftshift.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html)?

```
pA = fftshift(A);
pA(size(B,1),size(B,2)) = 0;  %// fill with zeros, high frequencies
pA = ifftshift(pA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with pre and post padding

```
A = ones(20,20);
B=zeros(33,33);
A = padarray(A,7,'symmetric','pre');
A = padarray(A',7,'symmetric','pre');
A = padarray(A,6,'symmetric','post');
A = padarray(A',6,'symmetric','post');
C = A.*B;
```

I just did padding according to symmetry. Since all the element of A were ones so according to symmetry it did pad it with ones. You can try different just need to write

```
help padarray
```

in command prompt to check the details how "padarray" actually works for different scenarios
Also for your code I pad the top pre with 7 and post with 6 to make it 13.
Hope this will help